# Unable to return mock data from an observable in Angular using Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, observable

In my angular application, I have a `PackagesService` which contains a `getPackages()` method, which when called populates the `packages$` property of the `PackagesService`. So, `packages$` is an observable which can be subscribed to get all the packages. So in my `PackagesComponent`, in the `ngOnInit()`, I called the `getPackages()` method of the `PackagesService` and the `packages$` property got populated and I used the data by subscribing to `packages$`. The application is working completely fine. But while testing, I am unable to mock the data returned by `packages$`. While running the test, it says **`this.packages$.subscribe is not a function`**. Below is my code:

PackagesComponent:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PackagesService } from './packages.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IPackage } from './packages.type';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-packages',
  templateUrl: './packages.component.html',
})
export class PackagesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() currentUser: any;
  @Input() orgInfo: any;

  
  public claimedPackages;
  public isPackageClaimed = false;
  constructor(private packagesService:PackagesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(this.currentUser);
    this.orgInfo = JSON.parse(this.orgInfo);
    this.packagesService.getPackages();
    this.packagesService.packages$.subscribe(res => { 
      this.claimedPackages= res.filter((package)=>{
        return package.status === 'claimed';
      });
      this.isPackageClaimed = this.claimedPackages.some(package=> {
        return this.currentUser.userPackage.includes(package.name);    
      });
    });  
  
  }
}
```

packages.component.spec.ts:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CommonTestUtilsModule, createComponent} from '@myproject/common/test-utils';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { PackagesComponent} from './packages.component';
import { PackagesService } from './packages.service';
import { IPackage} from './packages.type';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs'; 

const packages: IPackage[] = [
     {
      name: 'abc.com',
      status: 'claimed'
    }
]; 
const mockPackagesService = {
  getPackages: jest.fn(),
  packages$: jest.fn(()=>of(packages))
}

describe('PackagesComponent', () => {
  let component: PackagesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PackagesComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
     
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [CommonTestUtilsModule],
        declarations: [
          PackagesComponent,
        ],
        providers: [
          { provide: PackagesService , useValue: mockPackagesService }          
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      });
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    ({ fixture,component } = createComponent(PackagesComponent));
    component.currentUser = '{"meta":{"packageClaimTime":""}}';
    component.orgInfo = '{}';
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('claimedPackages', function(){
  
    it('should filter out claimed packages', function(){ 
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.claimedPackages.length).toBe(1);
    });
  }); 
});
```

Please help me to test this and check what is the value of `component.isPackageClaimed`. If needed, I will refactor my `PackagesComponent` if required. So please suggest any changes if I have made any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do `packages$: of(packages)` and it should work as expected.